# How to access adb directly from Android app?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to communicate with the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) from inside an app if the service has been loaded through USB?

Here is the use case: I can take a screenshot of the framebuffer through ADB on an unrooted phone with no problem, but it is a little slow to transmit the entire raw buffer over USB, especially if I want to take more than a frame every 2 seconds.  What I would like to do is access the framebuffer from inside an app on the phone which can then either transmit it over Wifi or do some compression first.  [ASL](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) doesn't work on Jellybean (they shut down the loophole to install native services on /data/local), so I would just like to connect to the ADB service via some socket or whatever and issue the framebuffer request that way.

I am ok with having to connect via USB to load the ADB service, but once connected, I would like to do processing on the phone itself before transmission.  And it must work on unrooted phones.

Is this possible?

Comment: Restart adb in wifi mode (via USB connected PC `adb tcpip <port>`)  & connect to your local adb instance via a socket. No idea how the protocol works but that's what https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot seems to do for example

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use the USB connector? You definitely can compress the data and then send it to a server via wifi. If you are good at REST, there must be a service out there you can post to freely

Comment: @zapl - Pure awesomeness!  This is exactly what I am looking for.  I don't know if it will be any faster, but I will try.  But I did test that I could connect to the bridge from the phone.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oneliner:

```
$ adb shell screencap -p \| gzip -c \> /mnt/sdcard/s.png.gz; adb pull /mnt/sdcard/s.png.gz;
```

Comment: Even faster:
`adb tcpip 12345`
`adb connect <ipaddr>:12345` (and you can disconnect USB here if you want)
`adb shell screencap -p /mnt/sdcard/s.png; adb pull /mnt/sdcard/s.png`
In my case, my host machine is slow, so uncompressing is even slower than just transmitting the bits